# Can I include social networks' name and logo in game credits without incurring in legal issues?

Tags: legal, copyright, trademark

I'm planning to release an alpha version of a video game I'm working on as a personal project. I'm also creating a "Credits" section, that is meant for me to give credit to used sources, and to other peoples whose work I've used, edited, or got inspired from (with their permission, of course); and obviously, my own name.

I'd also like to include links to social network pages, such as my Twitter profile, a YouTube channel, and eventually a GitHub page. As an indie developer, I want people who play my game to have the chance to contact me, tell me their impressions about my game(s), and stay updated on my progress as development goes on. It's another way to receive feedback and reach even more people.

I wonder if mentioning the names "Twitter", "YouTube", "GitHub", and any other, and including their original logo or an edited version, is somehow possible and/or allowed - perhaps including some sort of clause - and what are the limits I'm subject to when dealing with trademarked names and logos under copyright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you are permitted to do this, provided you comply with the guidelines set forth by the owner of the relevant trademark or copyright. But you'll generally need to look up the specifics for each logo or name you want to use. While there are commonalities in how most companies will permit you to use their logos ("don't change it, just use it to link to us, et cetera"), there may be specific concerns a company has with how their marks are presented.

Fortunately this isn't too hard to find, usually. Most companies will have a section on their website concerning how you are permitted to use their trademarks and related works. The relevant terms to search for are usually something like "brand assets," "brand use," "press kit," and so on.

For example:

- [Twitter's brand assets page](https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets).
- [YouTube's branding guidelines page](https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/).
- [GitHub's logos page](https://github.com/logos).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a not a lawyer and this should not be considered legal advice. If you just google for example 'youtube logo copyright' you get a good deal of information on the subject. As far as I know if you use the logos for a so called 'social line up' you need no special permission, but if for example a character in your game goes to Facebook in the game itself then you need to fill some permission forms to get the approved brand assets.

Comment: As long as you use the provided logos you should be fine.  If you start altering them then you might have a problem.

Comment: @Jon I've seen edited versions of several logos, such as the Twitter bird being a white silhouette instead of the classic azure shape, because such setting fitted best with a game theme, for example.